# How to secure a REST Web Service using Spring Security

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, spring-security

I am trying to secure my REST web services at the url /dispatcher/rest/**

My current design works fine if accessing the web service through browser - when I try to go to the REST url it redirects me to a login page to enter credentials, then redirects me to the web service data once logged in.

The problem is that when I try to access the web service through java code using RestTemplate, my code breaks.  This occurs even if the user has already logged in and authenticated.

My spring-security.xml config file:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/dispatcher/admin**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
 <intercept-url pattern="/dispatcher/rest/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/dispatcher/403" />
        <form-login 

            login-page="/dispatcher/login" 
            default-target-url="/dispatcher/admin"
            login-processing-url="/dispatcher/login_process"
            authentication-failure-url="/dispatcher/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/dispatcher/login?logout" logout-url = "/dispatcher/logout"/>
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
        </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService" >

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.shopping.services.MyUserDetailsService" />
</beans:beans>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Describe "when I try to access the web service through java code using RestTemplate, my code breaks". Try to isolate where the issue lies, either your `RestTemplate` related code is broken, or the security is. In the first case, you should also post the code you used to call your possibly secured API.

Comment: It is very uncommon to have a REST service protected by form login - are you sure that is what you want? Traditionally you would use basic authentication instead of form login, or if the services are called on behalf on an end user, you can use OAuth2.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to access the web service is the following:

```
 String username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
         String password = ((UserDetails) principal).getPassword();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
        Credentials defaultcreds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory(client));
        client.getState().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, defaultcreds);
        User x = restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8080/Online_Shopping/dispatcher/rest/hello",User.class);
```